# Python Import Error - yet again

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having some issues importing files in Python.

Lets say I have 2 folders (A and B) in my project directory. And in each of these folders,  I have included an **__init__.py** script so Python treats each of them as a module.

```
>> Root Project Directory
   >> Directory A
      .. __init__.py
      .. file X.py
   >> Directory B
      .. __init__.py
      .. file Y.py
```

If from script **X.py** in folder **A**, I try to import another script **Y.py** from folder **B**, I get an `ImportError. No module named B`. The import call is `from B import Y`.

I think this might have to do with Pythonpath because if I move script **X** to the root directory, the import works just fine. But if it is within another directory within the root directory, it doesn't work. I'm not sure what is wrong here.

Do I have to specify a python path for the root directory and for other new Python Projects?

Comment: How are you importing it? Show your actual import statement.

Comment: The import statement looks something like this:

`from B import Y` @Dan

Comment: How are you running your project. Is there a `main.py` somewhere or are you just doing `python A/X.py` or what?

Comment: I'm pretty much doing `python A/X.py`. Is it preferable to have a `main.py` script in the root directory? Also, is there a standard way to structure files and directories within a python project? I have come across different structures and I have always wondered if there was a standard... @Two-BitAlchemist

Comment: Depends. It's definitely preferable to have a single entry point and highly unusual to execute a subpackage or module directly from the command line. Reading: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are running. If you maintain the same structure and run as a module on the parent folder you will add the current directory to your python path. for example:

```
python2 -m A.X
```

On the same structure with X content being :

```
    from B.Y import b
    def a():
        return "a"
    print("HERe")
    print(a())
    print(b())
```

And Y being

```
    def b():
        return "b"
```

It will import it the way you desire